# Code to Change the TCP/IP configuration of the computer to DHCP

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, configuration, dhcp

I need to write C# code for the below request
 - My exe allows to change the TCP/IP configuration to DHCP while they select Dynamic IP button

I am in need of piece of code (or else) please provide suggessions/related links

Answer (score 0):

You can use the netsh tool, and you can invoke that from any programming language: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/257748

Comment: This will work only in Windows 2000. I need to work for Windows 7

Comment: Did you actually try? Netsh is available in Windows 7 and 8 as well. There may be minor differences in the command line parameters, but it's still the best way to solve your problem.